# How to eliminate mankind: concentrated nukes or scattered ones?

Tags: weapon-mass-destruction, nuclear-weapons, nuclear-war, nuclear-winter

Assume the entire governments of US and Russia are possessed by aliens from beyond to use nuclear weapons to exterminate the human race.

For now ignore the fact that there are may be more effective ways of using such mind control to eliminate mankind. Such as manipulating the economy, eliminating any one industry in the global food supply, etc.

They can either develop high yield weapons that would be fired in nations with high population and population density. Or they can be numerous and have much lesser individual yields, and then detonated to impact various cities and similar small areas with high population.

The objective is to maximise the death toll due to instant elimination/disfigurement and radiation poisoning via air (not water or food). Indirect kills such as those due to starvation or diseases due to the consequent failure of supply and manufacturing industries do not count. Kills due to nuclear strikes/test strikes by other nations that have been provoked do not count. These rules are simply to minimise speculation and get a more objective answer.

You can also assume that issues such as transportation of weapons and keeping of secrecy during the days leading to the detonation will be taken care of. Basically assume it is possible to reliably pinpoint any location on the world map and detonate a weapon there successfully without getting caught or failing. The only limitation is the current nuclear payload in possession of the US and Russian governments.

Looking at a population density map and the current capabilities of nuclear warheads, is it a better strategy to make concentrated strikes or scattered ones? You can also account for the varying abilities of people in different regions to get to safer regions immediately after the attacks.

Comment: Not a full answer, but: Nuke Yellowstone and see what happens.

Comment: Have you considered simply detonating nukes above the breadbasket region(s) and thus irradiating foodsources? Or is this out of question as well?

Comment: @dot Yes that would count as indirect kill.

Comment: At present the question is unclear. What do you mean by "concentrated" and "scattered" strikes? The most common nuclear bombs are 100 to 300 kilotons; for such bombs it makes no sense to detonate them less than 4 km apart, because two such bombs at 4 km distance will obliterate anything between them: is this to be considered "concentrated" or "scattered"?

Comment: "*Assume the entire governments of US and Russia are possessed by aliens from beyond*".  Don't you know we already are!!!  https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2013/10/how-spot-reptilians-runing-us-government/354496/

Comment: @dot_Sp0T: So how would irradiating food stores accomplish extermination?  Irradiation is actually a practical method of food preservation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_irradiation

Comment: @AlexP I'm assuming that bombs can be manufactured with payload significantly more than that. Detonating a separate bomb every few sq km would be considered scattered, while a single bomb for every hundred thousand square kilometres of surface area could be considered concentrated. Also the answer doesn't have to be one of the two options - concentrated vs scattered. Anything in between will also do.

Answer (score 3):

### Use [cobalt bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt_bomb)

The principle is rather simple: use a nuclear detonation to transmute ordinary cobalt-59 into radioactive cobalt-60, which is scattered and turns into nuclear fallout with a half-life of several years. This way, with enough bombs, you can contaminate the entire surface of the planet with highly radioactive fallout, rendering it uninhabitable for a century.

This is one of the most hideous weapons ever developed by humankind. Fortunately for us, it seems to never have gone further than paper. Fortunately for the aliens, it is pretty easy to convert standard nukes to cobalt nukes.

As they have control over both the US and Russian governments, it is very easy to create an incentive for building them: they are the ultimate MAD system.

Here is a plan: tensions grow, or grow again, if we are after the Cold War. Let's say, purely hypothetically, that the US start randomly invading countries in a populist, ill-defined military strategy which, while a blessing for domestic arms dealers, horribly backfires and start destabilizing entire regions of the globe. And then cancel existing nuclear treaties abut anti-ballistic systems, previously ratified to avoid a new nuclear arms race. Then Russia start invading neighbours, use mass-disinformation campaigns, supports a scatter of far-right groups and criminal networks in order to destabilize the West, and develop new generations of nuclear weapons. To anyone not in the know, this appears to be a new but unsurprising, if worrying, symptom of the aggressive incompetence political classes everywhere are so often affected with.

In fact, they are merely a pretext to justify building (or, in the case of Russia, possibly resurrecting) a nuclear dead man's switch: in the name of safety, an Armageddon device is built, that will launch and detonate enough cobalt bombs to kill literally the entire planet in case of attack against the nation. Of course, all safety measures have been taken to avoid accidental release and all that.

But as the aliens control both governments, as soon as both systems are on-line (preferably before they are officially announced, so they are still useless as a MAD system), they can easily engineer a crisis ending up in a nuclear conflict. A good subject would be, say, simultaneous "Those fools are build a nuclear dead man's switch! We have to take them out before they finish it!" For inspiration, look up the several times where it nearly happened before the aliens even arrived in the first place. Just be sure no pesky little human somewhere in the machine shows undue initiative and prevents the whole thing from blowing up like last times.

Another advantage of this plan is, if some of those ridiculously clever apes actually survive a century in some bunkers or whatnot (I wouldn't count on it, but you never know) and somehow start building a new civilisation from the ruins of the previous ones, they won't even be able to guess that the aliens were responsible. The plan perfectly mimics the kind of systemic incompetence that humans are accustomed with, and those who may believe an alien theory already invented countless and often highly flawed conspiracy theories to explain other cases, which helps further disguising it. Unless they find working mind-control devices or other obviously alien traces, they will have simply no way to know what really happened.

Answer (score 1):

## Cost per Megaton

There is not exactly an open market value for nukes, but I expect a very uneven chart. High costs per kiloton for very small yields, then bumps as fission becomes fission-fusion becomes fission-fusion-fission.

## Kilodeaths per Megaton

If you look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_nuclear_explosions#Summary_of_the_effects), there is a diminishing return for bigger weapons:

- For 1 kt, the lethal radius of radiation is largest, with an area of 1.9 square kilometres.
- For 20 kt, you get 3rd degree burns over 20 square kilometres. Civilian buildings will be demolished over 9 square kilometres.
  *1 square kilometre per kt*.
- For 1 mt, third degree burns over 450 square kilometres.
  *0.45 square kilometres per kt.*
- With 20 mt, it is third degree burns over 4,500 square kilometres.
  *0.23 square kilometres per kt.*

(I'm assuming that with the attendant breakdown of healthcare, third degree burns will be lethal. That won't be true in *every* case.)

## Fratricide

In a nuclear context, it means that one exploding weapon destroys other, not-yet-exploded weapons nearby.
This could be prevented with precision timing, but it is something to keep in mind.

## Summary:

If they can get efficient assembly lines going, more smaller weapons should be more lethal. But the differences are small enough that cost-per-megaton considerations might alter the outcome.